# Unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class even with error handling

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

```
Sub storage_data()
'declare range

Dim res As Variant
Dim dw As Variant
Set Rng = Sheet16.Range("G17:H46") 'product name in H col and quantity in G col

' to deduct from storage
For s = 3 To 30

    On Error Resume Next
    'all the product's name in B col and storage quantity in L col of sheet14
    
        res = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet14.Range("B" & s).Value, Rng, 1, False)
        'FYI I tried just "Application.VLookup(Sheet14.Range("B" & s).Value, Rng, 1, False)" too
        dw = Sheet14.Range("L" & s).Value
        dw = dw - res
        
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `VLookup` needs the lookup value in the first column not in the second as you are trying to use it. If you would switch the columns, then it could work with 2 instead of 1. But of course, there are other options, e.g. using `Application.Match`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Lookup Using `Application.Match`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub storage_data()
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Sheet16.Range("G17:H46")
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    
    With Sheet14
        For s = 3 To 30
            cIndex = Application.Match(.Range("B" & s).Value, srg.Columns(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("L" & s).Value = .Range("L" & s).Value _
                    - srg.Columns(2).Cells(cIndex)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```